# Are there any "Neutrinian" standard candles?

Tags: astronomy, neutrinos, supernova

Are there any theoretical models/investigations of object far away that could act as some type of neutrinian standard candles? That is, they spew out neutrinos of with some know characteristics that could be used to obtain information about other observables?

See [here](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/nov/21/icecube-finds-cosmic-neutrinos-at-the-south-pole#comments) and [here](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/dec/13/cosmic-neutrinos-named-physics-world-2013-breakthrough-of-the-year) where they discuss how [IceCube](http://icecube.wisc.edu/) has detected cosmic neutrinos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would expect type Ia supernovas to be standard candles in neutrinos for the same reason they work that way in light. Alas, with the current detector packages they are only good in our local group (this would be considerably improved with the implementation of a GADZOOKS!-like scheme to gadolinium-doped superK or by several proposed but very expensive next generation neutrino telescopes).